# Force npm to use my fork for all modules

Tags: npm, package.json, yarnpkg

I have forked a project on Github ([parse5](https://github.com/ghego1/parse5)). The edits I made to `parse5` are  to fix an incompatibility between `@angular/platform-server` and `parse5`, and with my fixes it would work fine.

I have added my fork to my `dependencies` (`"parse5": "https://github.com/ghego1/parse5.git"`) in `package.json` and it is installed as expected.

However, while my fork is installed, npm and yarn also install a new module from the `parse5` repository under `platform-server/node-modules`. Unfortunately `platform-server` then uses that version, thus crashing the app.

Is there a way to "force" npm and yarn to always use my specific fork, in all modules and submodules?

EDIT

By manually removing the `parse5` repository under `platform-server/node-modules`, 
`@angular/platform-server` uses my fork installed in the root folder `node-modules`, which does not crash the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Working off the idea of manually removing the repository under `platform-server/node-modules` from the EDIT in the question:*

In `package.json` add a `postinstall` step in your `package.json > scripts` section to automatically remove the unwanted version of the installed package e.g. `"postinstall": "rm -rf ./node_modules/platform-server/node-modules/parse5"`